# Rails 3 - Missing Index Paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake

I'm having a pretty weird problem with one of my rails apps. I think I'm probably doing something really silly that I just haven't been able to identify. My problem is that, I seem to be missing about half of my index paths.

For example, if my controller is "foos" for a model foo, I'll have the:

```
foos POST   /foos(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"foos"}
```

But no GET option which would usually be as:

```
foos GET    /foos(.:format)   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"foos"}
```

Below I'll show you my actually code, to help me recover my missing index routes.

routes.rb:

```
resource :announcements, :controller => "announcements" do
  resources :comments
  member do
    post 'vote'
  end
end
```

routes for the announcements part:

```
announcements      POST   /announcements(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"announcements"}
new_announcements  GET    /announcements/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"announcements"}
edit_announcements GET    /announcements/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"announcements"}
                   GET    /announcements(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"announcements"}
                   PUT    /announcements(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"announcements"}
                   DELETE /announcements(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"announcements"}
```

As you can see there is no get / index. In my controller, I have the simply index method defined...

```
def index
  @announcements = Announcement.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml  { render :xml => @announcements }  
  end
end
```

I really don't understand why I don't have this index path. It's happening on several other controllers as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: In the console, `app.announcements_path` returns a method missing error, in addition to the others that have missing index paths.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is because you're using the singularized version of `resources` (`resource`). There is no `index` action route generated for these. You should change this to be the pluralized version, and remove `:controller` from the line too.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I knew it was something silly I did. Appreciate it~